# Highlight line chart single value in MPAndroidChart

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I am using [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart), I want to use

```
  setDrawCircles(true);
  setDrawValues(true);
```

only for selected value from line chart in mpchart libary. Means I do not want to draw label and circle on whole data set which can be easily achieved using above methods. I need to draw label and circle only for one value from chart. I have implemented onChartValueSelected and I do not know what should be done in onValueSelected I have tried many things. I achieved this in version 2.5.5 but now I am using version 3.0.0 and facing issue.